# The number of operations to multiply L by U?

Tags: matrices, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

I have the following $A=LU$
while $L$ is is lower triangular matrix and $U$ is an upper triangular matrix, the size of both $L$ and $U$ is $N\times N$.

The question is how many operations are required to multiply both matrices to get $A$?

I got that the result is $\sum_{i=1}^N  \sum_{j=1}^N \min(i,j)$ but how to calculate that?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I have edited my question, it's related somehow to min but I need the specific answer

Comment: Do both $L$ and $U$ include the diagonal ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\min(i,j)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^i\min(i,j)+\sum_{j=i+1}^n\min(i,j)\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^ij+\sum_{j=i+1}^ni\right)
\\=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i(i+1)}2+\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i)i
=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n((2n+1)i-i^2).$$

Comment: But this means that the answer is O(N^3), it should be O(N^2)

Comment: @clark_smith: why ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

In general we can decompose the minimum as sum of indicator of whether an entries is bigger than $i$.

We have

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N\min(i,j) = \sum_{i=1}^N i^2=\frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$$

Comment: But this means that the answer is O(N^3), it should be O(N^2)

Comment: perhaps try a few small examples to check if the answer agrees?